# TYPO3 v. 10.4 URI Builder Produces Sometimes Faulty Language Links in the Cache

Tags: routes, uribuilder, typo3-10.x

After clicking a while through the web site, the pages in the cache change suddenly to faulty pages. One part of the links then are written with a-tags that don't have a href attributes. The other part are proper links to the correct page but to another language. It happens mostly to the default language (German). Some links are appended with &L=3 or &L=4 after the last forward slash. The id of the language changes. After clearing the cache the site works well until the next sudden break-down of the links. When the cache stays switched off everything works fine.

```
base: 'https://metu.de'
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: de_DE.UTF8
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: '0'
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: en
    locale: en_US.UTF8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: us
    languageId: '1'
  -
    title: French
    enabled: true
    base: /fr/
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_FR.UTF8
    iso-639-1: fr
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: fr
    languageId: '2'
  -
    title: Italian
    enabled: true
    base: /it/
    typo3Language: it
    locale: it_IT.UTF8
    iso-639-1: it
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: it
    languageId: '4'
  -
    title: Russian
    enabled: true
    base: /ru/
    typo3Language: ru
    locale: ru_RU.UTF8
    iso-639-1: ru
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: ru
    languageId: '5'
  -
    title: Spanish
    enabled: true
    base: /es/
    typo3Language: es
    locale: es_ES.UTF8
    iso-639-1: es
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: es
    languageId: '3'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
websiteTitle: Metu
```

What might be the problem? It isn't possible to switch off the URI builder. How can I track down the error?

Comment: does the faulty behavior change when you enter the correct value for `hreflang` of each language? currently the keys exist but no values are assigned.

Comment: Thank You David, I added the hreflang values. I'll check on the behavior and I'll post it here. Thank you again.

Comment: still the same faulty behavior. I conclude from that, that
1. it is not a configuration error
2. caching has to be involved since no_cache = 1 produces no error.
3. the default (German) language must be somehow different.

For clarification, only the German (default) language pages are produced with wrong or not working links. The other languages work OK, there is just a ?L=4 or ?L=3 appended to the correct URL. This has no influence on the navigation thru those languages.

Comment: is it possible that not all of your slugs are unique?

Comment: after carefully checking the slug entries, there are some repeating slug entries, like /start/contenido but they are for the same page in different languages which means that the generated URL's are different, i.e. es/start/contenido and it/start/contenido Most likely this is not the cause of the error, or could it be though?

Comment: It seems so, even I'm not sure about it. In any case I'd file an issue on https://forge.typo3.org as it looks like a bug for me.